# The language of any constant-time Turing machine is regular

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, regular-languages

> Suppose we have a Turing machine $M$ so that there is a constant $t$ such that the Turing machine always runs in time $t$ or less. Prove that the language of $M$ is regular.

This seems to be a pretty well-known fact, but despite my research, I cannot seem to find a proof of this anywhere. Does someone know of one?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It would have been easier to edit and fix it before you wrote an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If the machine runs in time $t$ on all inputs then its decision only depends on the first $t$ symbols of the input.

Comment: So if M accepts only strings of length t or less, then it is a finite language and we are done. Otherwise, M accepts a string of length greater than t. Since the machine runs in time t or less, its decision only depends on the first t symbols. So we can express the language by the regex w1|...|wk|w1sigma*|...|wksigma*, where w1 through wk are all the strings that M accepts with length t or less (here, sigma is the given alphabet). Is this correct?

Comment: Right, that's the idea, though you might have to mix your two types.